# Excel IF AND OR Condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to create a project report where i am required to check status of the project and basis that i have to generate a value by looking at Hrs

Example Sheet "Dump" has Raw data which has 2 columns. In one of the column i have "Status" and another has Hrs.

I have to check if "Status" is complete and hrs are "0" or blank then the output should be the value of hrs column else we need show "Missing Value". if Status is anything apart from complete then we need to show blank in the output.

I am using the below and not able to get the desired result.

```
=IF(Dump!L7="COMPLETE",IF(OR(AND(Dump!L7="COMPLETE",Dump!H7=""),Dump!H7,AND(Dump!L7="COMPLETE",Dump!H7=0)),Dump!H7,"Value MISSING"),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you get your desire result with this formula?

```
=IF(Dump!L7="COMPLETE",IF(OR(Dump!H7=0,Dump!H7),IF(Dump!H7="","",Dump!H7),"Value MISSING"),"")
```

This basically refactors some logical redundancies and actually returns the value of " " as it is.

Because"

> "Excel assigns the value 0 to a blank cell."

[Excel: why the value of a blank cell is zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191270/excel-why-the-value-of-a-blank-cell-is-zero)