# Trouble with IFFALSE issue

Tags: excel

Trying to get rid of the returned 0 in a IF formula and just have it remain blank if no data. This is for a work Calander and if there is no data for that date, i would like it blank, not a 0

this is the formula

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(DATE($G$28,$H$28,E12),'2024 Activities Schedule'!$B$7:$B$91,0)),"",INDEX('2024 Activities Schedule'!$C$7:$C$91,MATCH(DATE($G$28,$H$28,E12),'2024 Activities Schedule'!$B$7:$B$91,0)))
```

I have tried changing the 0 to "", to no avail.

I want it to use the data IF TRUE, but leave it blank iF FALSE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62682467